# Copy only row indices of Mat from findNonZero function in C++ OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mat

I am trying to convert MATLAB code to C++.
In MATLAB, I use the `find` function to get the indices of a vector and then copy these to other variables. For example:

```
idx = find(A>s);
B = idx;
% A, idx, and B are vectors; s is a scalar
```

In C++ OpenCV (C++14 / OpenCV 3.4.10) I know I can use the `findNonZero` function, but it returns both row and column indices:

```
double s;
Mat1d A;
Mat1i B;
Mat idx;
.
.
.
findNonZero(A>s, idx);
```

I do not know how I can copy only row-indices directly (without using a `for` loop).  I thought it could be done by defining `Mat2i idx` and using `mixChannels` like this:

```
Mat2i idx;
findNonZero(A>s, idx);
B = Mat1i::zeros(idx.size());
int from_to[] = {1, 0};
mixChannels(&idx, 1, &B, 1, from_to, 1);
```

However, I get the following error while running the `findNonZero` function:

> OpenCV(3.4.10) Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((Mat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray::create,

But if I set `Mat idx`, I get another error while running the `mixChannel` function:

> OpenCV(3.4.10) Error: Assertion failed (j < nsrcs && src[j].depth() == depth) in cv::mixChannels,

I'm not sure what I should do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB's `find` determines the **column-major** indices of where values are nonzero in the input matrix.  This is true if you specify the single output version of it.  If you provide two output variables, that generates both the row and column locations of the nonzero values in the input. In your example you have provided the single output version of `find` so I will be working with this.

OpenCV's `cv::Mat` lays out the image in **row-major**.  I'm assuming you would like the row-major indices.  If so, since `cv::findNonZero` outputs both the row and column coordinates, you must loop through the output coordinates yourself and create the row-major indices.  You shouldn't be afraid of using loops here.  In fact, `for` loops over `cv::Mat`s are optimised for quick access.  Therefore:

```
Mat2i idx;
Mat1d A; // Define somewhere else
double s; // Define somewhere else

findNonZero(A > s, idx);
B = Mat1i::zeros(idx.total());
for (int i = 0; i < idx.total(); ++i) {
    B.at<int>(i) = idx.at<Point>(i).y * A.cols + idx.at<Point>(i).x;
}
```

`B` will contain the row-major indices in a `cv::Mat1i`.  If I have misunderstood your inquiry and simply want the row locations of the nonzero values, then it's just:

```
Mat2i idx;
Mat1d A; // Define somewhere else
double s; // Define somewhere else

findNonZero(A > s, idx);
B = Mat1i::zeros(idx.total());
for (int i = 0; i < idx.total(); ++i) {
    B.at<int>(i) = idx.at<Point>(i).y;
}
```

Remember you are only iterating over the nonzero values, so the worst case complexity is to iterate over the locations that are nonzero.

Comment: Yes, I just "simply want the row locations of the nonzero values"! haha. But I'm not sure if using for-loop is the fastest way? (I mean the performance...)

Comment: It is. `cv::Mat`s are designed to be iterated over quickly. The compiler will optimize the code to make it fast. The only exception to this are operations even more optimized for access, like filtering.